# Inner function in python doesn't return at the right place

Tags: python, return, control-flow

In the below code from an inner function of mine, no matter the scores the only value returned is `(0, None)`.  I can see that the `for` loop terminates when a team has hit either the victory or mercy thresholds, but that does not act as the return value for the whole function. I do not remember return statements working like this, so can someone please explain why this is happening?

```py
    def victory_check() -> Tuple[Optional[int], Optional[Team]]:
        scores_all_bad: bool = True
        for team in tea_lst:
            print(team.score)  # debug
            if team.score >= victory_threshold:
                return 1, team
            if team.score < mercy_rule:
                return -1, team
            if team.score > bad_ai_end:
                scores_all_bad = False
        if scores_all_bad:
            return -1, None
        return 0, None
```

The `Team` object is made with the following.  The test harness adds a random integer between -12 and 14 to each team's score to pretend to play a hand.  The `Team.score` values are correctly reflected in the print statement.

```py
class Team:
    players: List[Player]
    score: int = 0
    bid: int

    def __init__(self, players: List[Player]):
        self.players = players
```

Comment: Can you give more clarity regarding how your inputs look along with how your outputs are looking?

Comment: " I can see that the for loop terminates when a team has hit either the victory or mercy thresholds" does it though? Or does it coincidentally terminate after that? Because `return` does indeed return from the (closest) enclosing function. And since select is not broken, there's probably something you're missing in the execution of your code. And since you're not providing the means of reproduction it's difficult to analyse the issue.

Comment: At any rate, using a few synthetic values things seem to work as expected: given bad_ai_end = 0;victory_threshold = 9; mercy_rule = -10 and sequences of a single team with scores 10, 5, -5 and -100 I get results of `1, team`, `0, None`, `-1, None` and `-1, team` which is in line with what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: It turns out that the error was in the testing loop and not the function I thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `team_list` looks like. Assuming it is a list of dictionaries, this code works as expected.

```py
team_lst = [{'score': 40}]
def victory_check():
    scores_all_bad: bool = True
    for team in team_lst:
        print(team.keys())
        print(team.get('score'))  # debug
        if team.get('score') >= 5:
            return 1, team
        if team.get('score') < 5:
            return -1, team
        if team.get('score') > 100:
            scores_all_bad = False
    if scores_all_bad:
        return -1, None
    return 0, None
```

Answer (score -2):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement),

> return leaves the current function call with the expression list (or
>   None) as return value.

So the only way afaik for a function to execute (not return) multiple return statements is when you have a try-except block running with an argument in finally block. Something like below. To be clear, (Python internally executes two returns but only one actually gets returned)

```
def nums(list_ofvals):

    score = True
    try:
        for v in list_ofvals:
            if v == 1:
                return "one return", 1

            elif v == 3:
                return "three return", 3
    except:
        pass

    finally:
        if score == True:
            return "true score"
        else:
            pass

print(nums([1])) #function call
```

Comment: While it's possible to overwrite a previously "executed" return statement with another return statement in a `finally` block, that's definitely bad style and should almost always be avoidable. In your example, a well-placed `break` from the loop can achieve the same and is way clearer.

Comment: I agree with that. My argument is that the only way afaik to fire two return statement is by using a try/except block with finally which obviously overwrites as you said. So the question posted by this user cannot work the way he says it does. My code is just an example of what is possible and what is not...